# Add support for mb_substr on CentOs with cPanel/WHM

Tags: centos

How do I add support for mb_substr on my CentOs server running cPanel/WHM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added support for mb_substr by using Easy::Apache in WHM. When building a new configuration i chose the option extensive options and checked for the mb_substr.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about the [`mb_substr` function in PHP](http://php.net/mb_substr).  *Without* the interference of cPanel, you'd just be able to install the `php-mbstring` or `php53-mbstring` package at the command line and restart Apache.

Most web hosting control panel software tends to sink tendrils deep inside the configuration of software it deems important, such as PHP.  Verify that the PHP version installed is provided by the system package manager, and you should be all set.  One way to do this would be to compare the installed PHP version string against the version that the package manager thinks is installed.  On CentOS, you'd do this by running `php --version`, then checking the version string against what `yum info php` or `yum info php53` provides.

It's quite possible that the PHP version installed isn't done through the normal package management mechanism.  You may need to ask cPanel technical support for assistance in that case.  Updating or altering the configuration of cPanel-managed things can break the world horribly, and you should proceed with caution.